# Время вывод echo после отправки формы

Tags: php, email

Добрый день, вопрос такой, есть форма отправки сообщения, все работает, единственное смена сообщений с "форма отправки" до "Cообщение успешно отправленно." после нажатия на кнопку "отправить" составляет примерно 5сек. По мне так это долго. Можно как-нибудь ускорить процесс смены вывода echo?

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
   $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
   $mess = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['text']));
   $mail = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['email']));

   if(empty($_POST['email']))
   {
      echo "<p>Вы не указали свой E-mail!</p>";
    }
   elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-z_\.]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i", $mail))
   {
      echo "<p>Вы ввели некорректный E-mail!</p>";
   }
   else
   { 
        $to  = 'email@mail.ru' . ', '; 
        $from = 'email2@mail.ru';
        $subject = "Сообщение с сайта";
        $message = "Имя: ".$name. "\r\nПочта: ".$mail."\r\nСообщение: ".$mess.';';
        $headers = "Content-type:  text/plain; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: <vmail2@mail.ru>\r\n";
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($result){ 
            echo "<p>Cообщение успешно отправлено.</p>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>Cообщение не отправлено. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: проблема в тормозящем сервере, с кодом всё в порядке

Comment: Сколько времени выполняется функция `mail`?

Comment: Судя по коду проблема в том что долго отправляется почта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, разобралась сама, в локальную папку отправляет моментально.

Comment: оффтоп: а почему слева от собаки не разрешены знаки "минус" и "плюс"? вот тут `^[0-9a-z_\.]+@`. вполне допустимо так `^[-+0-9a-z_.]+@` (и точку тут можно не экранировать)

Comment: Почитайте это https://habrahabr.ru/post/274985/ и вот это https://habrahabr.ru/post/175375/

Comment: ваш код выводит значение только после отправки, значит тормозит сама отправка, т.е почтовый сервер. Решения через Ajax ничем не помогут, разве что можно какую-то крутилку подвесить, чтобы было видно, что что-то происходит, а не просто зависло

Comment: Да, можно, для этого нужно оптимизировать настройки сервера

Comment: Дайте более иформативный ответ. Как можно оптимизировать настройки сервера?

Comment: Вот пара полезных ссылок: Апач: https://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/05/27/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-apache/  Nginx: https://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/04/24/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-nginx/

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но данный ресурс не является ссылкообменником. Информация будет полезной, если она будет не в ссылке, и не в комментарии, а прямо в теле ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно. Обработайте запрос пользователя и сохраните сообщение где-нибудь (например в базе данных), после этого сообщите пользователю, что сообщение отправлено. А уведомление на почту отправляйте отдельным скриптом, например, запускающимся по расписанию ([cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)). То есть каждые пять минут скрипт проверяет нет ли новых сообщений от пользователей и если есть, то рассылает уведомления на почту.

Можно ещё отправлять сообщения js'ом, без перезагрузки страницы. Тогда можно сделать Отправка... -> Отправлено! Пользователи будут довольны даже если ваш сервер немного задумается.

Подробнее

На виртуальных хостингах обычно есть "кнопка" (пункт в меню, раздел настроек) для настройки планировщика cron. Идея в том, чтобы добавить в него регулярный запуск (раз в пять минут, например) вашего скрипта, который будет проверять наличие новых сообщений и отправлять уведомления на почту.

При разработке вам cron не нужен, надо только протестировать команду, которую он будет выполнять.

Как сохранять новые сообщения. Лучше всего в базу данных, например в SQLite или MySQL. Для работы с ними в PHP есть библиотека  [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Опыт работы с базами данных вам обязательно пригодится, поэтому не поленитесь разобраться как это работает.

После того, как сохранили сообщение в базе, можно сообщить пользователю о успехе отправки (его сообщение теперь не потеряется).

Для радости пользователей запрос на отправку часто отправляется [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)'ом. То есть, пользователь жмёт кнопку отправить, но вместо стандартного перехода на страницу отправки, запрос выполняется незаметно для пользователя (при этом у него обычно отображается какой-нибудь спиннер "идёт отправка"), а когда запрос отработал текущая страница модифицируется и пользователь видит сообщение об успехе/неудаче.

Comment: а можно немного подробнее. я только начинаю осваивать php, было бы шикарно так реализовать

Comment: @Елена да. Сейчас напишу.